# react native maps custom Tile Overlay log x,y,z

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using custom tile overlay from react-native-maps :

```
<MapView.UrlTile
   /**
   * The url template of the tile server. The patterns {x} {y} {z} will be replaced at runtime
   * For example, http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
   */
    urlTemplate={this.state.urlTemplate}
  />
```

I am able to display tiles using this url template :

```
urlTemplate={'http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'}
```

Now I would like to access z, x and y variables to log requested tiles.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?